# Decomposing a graph into $N$ planar sub-graphs that can be drawn on $N$ planes.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I would like to ask you if there is a way for checking if we can decompose a specific graph into $N$ planar sub-graphs that can be drawn on $N$ planes without an edge crossing any of the planes.

Comment: The minimum value of $N$ for which this can be done is called the "thickness" of the graph. According to Wikipedia, calculating the thickness of a graph is an NP-hard problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thickness_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [Steve Kass](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/60500/steve-kass) essentially answered this question in the comments:

> The minimum value of $N$ for which this can be done is called the [thickness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thickness_(graph_theory)) of the graph. According to Wikipedia, calculating the thickness of a graph is an $NP$-hard problem.